# how to jump to the next open directory in vim nerdtree plugin

Tags: vim, nerdtree

For example, my file tree looks like this:

```
+/root/  
    -/close/  
    +/open/  
        aa.html  
        bb.xml
```

If the cursor is in root line, how to jump to `open` directory as quickly as possible?

Each time I need to use the 'j','k' key, it's not convenient enough!

Comment: I wrote a simple script that might help, it was discussed in another [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010575/how-can-i-jump-to-the-first-file-starting-with-a-given-character-in-nerdtree)

Answer (score 3):

The NERDTree buffer is also a regular buffer, so you can use e.g. the search command: `/open<Enter>` to navigate to a particular sub-directory, or in your case `/op<Enter>`.

Or if you're on the first line, <kbd>3j</kbd> to move down by 3 lines.